# Hide unrelated parent nodes but child node in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to do this thing in D3.js but unable to find a way to do it.

What I want to do is, when a person clicks on the root node (level 0), it should show the child elements (level 1). When a person clicks on one of the child nodes (level 1) it should show its childrens (level 2) and the parent and parent-of-parent (level 1, this what the user clicked), but hide all the unrelated parents (from level 1).

Let me explain you this with pictures.

[image: Node Diagram]

Comment: In jQuery you can hide the siblings of a node by calling `$('selector').siblings().hide()`

Comment: Are you trying to do this with d3.layout.tree(), or are you asking about a more general case with DOM elements?

Comment: Yeah! I'm trying to do it with d3.layout.tree().

Comment: What have you tried thus far? What is your setup? What exactly does not work? To get further help you need to provide some code. Please consider putting together a JSFiddle to play around with.

Comment: Have you seen this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) covering a collapsible tree layout? If not exactly what you are after, it lays out the basics pretty well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/4fea200ebebb273aa4df

I forked http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 and made a few changes:

1. Added a new property to each node `.all_children` which keeps track of all children.  We need this, or something similar since `.children` contains the child nodes currently displayed, and `._children` is used by the existing code to determine if a node contains children or not (and sets the style accordingly).

   Also added a `.hidden` property that helps to determine whether or not the node should be displayed.

   These are added after loading the data:

   ```
   d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
       root = flare;
       root.x0 = height / 2;
       root.y0 = 0;

       function collapse(d) {
           if (d.children) {
               d.all_children = d.children;
               d._children = d.children;
               d._children.forEach(collapse);
               d.children = null;
               d.hidden = true;
           }
       }

       root.all_children = root.children;
       root.children.forEach(collapse);
       root.children.forEach(function(d) { d.hidden = false; });
       root.hidden = false;
       update(root);
   });
   ```
2. Updated the `update` function to reflect the new changes and only draw the nodes that are supposed to be drawn:

   ```
   function update(source) {

       // Compute the new tree layout.
       var nodes = tree.nodes(root).filter(function(d) { return !d.hidden; }).reverse(),
       links = tree.links(nodes);
   ```

   The `nodes` variable is set to only contain nodes that are NOT hidden.
3. Updated the `click` handler to correctly set the state of the nodes in the display:

   ```
   // Toggle children on click.
   function click(d) {
       if (d.children) {
           d._children = d.children;
           d.children = null;
           if (d._children) {
               d._children.forEach(function(n) { n.hidden = true; });

               if (d.parent) {
                   d.parent.children = d.parent.all_children;
                   d.parent.children.forEach(function(n) {
                       n.hidden = false;
                   });
               }
           }
       } else {
           d.children = d._children;
           d._children = null;
           if (d.children) {
               d.children.forEach(function(n) { n.hidden = false; });

               if (d.parent) {
                   d.parent.children = [d,];
                   d.parent.children.filter(function(n) { return n !== d; }).forEach(function(n) {
                       n.hidden = true;
                   });
               }
           }
       }
       update(d);
   }
   ```

   The first part of the `if` statement is called when we're collapsing a node, in which case, we need to display all of the siblings of the clicked node by setting `d.parent.children` to `d.parent.all_children` and setting each of those nodes to `.hidden = false`. And we need to hide all the children of the clicked node by setting `d.children = null` and then setting each node in `d._children` to hidden.

   The second part of the `if` statement is called when we're expanding a node, in which case, we need to hide its siblings (set `.hidden` to `true`) and update the `.children` property of the clicked node's `.parent` node so that only the clicked node is listed as a child.